# URL strategy for local business and multilingual website

Tags: subdomain, keywords, local-seo, multilingual, site-structure

I'm trying to find the best structure for a local business service that has a multilingual website.

Actually, the website has a simple structure:
www.brand.com/fr/
www.brand.com/en/

I'm considering to replace www by taxi, which is the business activity in order to give some context to the brand name which has no keyword related to the activity.
The URL could look like that
taxi.brand.com/fr/
taxi.brand.com/en/

With specific pages targeted for locations it could look like that
taxi.brand.com/fr/location/
taxi.brand.com/en/location/

Another alternative would be to use subdomains for locations
location.brand.com/fr/

Or to use the language code as subdomain
fr.mydomain.com/location/

What are your thoughts on the optimal structure from an SEO perspective?

Comment: Sorry but multilingual questions regarding domains and urls have been asked many times in various forms all over Pro Webmasters. You can also find many [related answers and questions by using the search function](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Url+multilingual+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: I had looked before at other related questions, but I had a doubt to use or not the taxi keyword as subdomain and would like a specific answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best strategy for you would be to have 
www.brand.com/location/ and for other languages language.brand.com/location/

However, remember to tell search engines that you have same pages in different languages like this - 
`<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.brand.com/" />
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://espanol.brand.com/" />`

Why?

1. location.brand.com is not as good as brand.com/location/ SEO-wise as link juice don't flow as good on sub-domains as they do in hierarchical structure (there is matt cutt video on this - search on youtube)
2. taxi.brand.com will be very difficult for return visitors to remember and may not give much of additional advantage in SEO. Keep it short and don't make it complex just for SEO purpose. However, if you have other services like taxi, hotels, etc. then you may consider taxi.brand.com, hotels.brand.com etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll switch to a simple structure as suggested. The stats show that 67.7% of visitors speak french and 29% speak english. Should I redirect users based on to their language automatically when they reach the main domain? If yes, should I send french users to a subdomain fr.brand.com or let them on www.brand.com?

Comment: I think you should go through this page - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192